# JavaScript adding on elements from a dropdown box

Tags: javascript, html

Hi guys so i am trying to complete a small task of helping the user pick the right ski size, So they would enter there age and height and what kind of ski's they would get, so freestyle or classic and it would calculate the length of the skis.
Now i figured out how to do it with age and height when they enter it. So i went by :

1-4 years: body length + 0 cm.

5-8 years: body length + 10 cm

9-12 years: body length + 15 cm etc etc

That part works fine. But what i am trying to do now is when the user picks classic it adds an extra 10cm on to the final size and when they pick freestyle it adds on an extra 20cm . However this part i am not to sure how to accomplish and  need help on.

HTML:

```
<form name="sizeForm">
Age: <input type="text" name="age" size="10"><br />
Height: <input type="text" name="height" size="10"><br />
                 <select name="typeski" class="select" id="name" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type of ski" >
        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please Select Type Of Skis. . . . . . .</option>
        <option value="0">Classic</option>
        <option value="1">Freestyle</option>
                </select>
<input type="button" value="Calculate Size" onClick="finalsize()"><br />
Your Ski Size: <input type="text" name="ski" size="10"><br />
<input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

js:

```
function finalsize() {
  var age = parseInt(document.sizeForm.age.value)
  var height = parseInt(document.sizeForm.height.value)
  var typeski = parseInt(document.sizeForm.typeski.value)
  if (age > 0 && height > 0) {   
    var size = height;
    if (age > 1 && age <= 4) size += 0;
    else if (age >= 5 && age <= 8) size += 10;
    else if (age >= 9 && age <= 12) size += 15;
    document.sizeForm.ski.value = size;
  }
  else {
    alert("Please Fill in everything correctly")
  }
}
```

Hopefully after this has been fixed i will try and make this into a vue.js app , as it seems to be better etc but for now trying to solve this

Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is just to make the `value` of the type options equal to the amount that you want to add on for that type.

Then just add the `value` of the control directly onto the size. Alternatively you could use a lookup table, but this is simpler.

In the example below I used +10 for Classic and +20 for Freestyle because your question said +10 for both, which seemed like a typo :)

```js
function finalsize() {
  var age = parseInt(document.sizeForm.age.value)
  var height = parseInt(document.sizeForm.height.value)
  var typeski = parseInt(document.sizeForm.typeski.value)
  if (age > 0 && height > 0) {   
    var size = height;
    if (age > 1 && age <= 4) size += 0;
    else if (age >= 5 && age <= 8) size += 10;
    else if (age >= 9 && age <= 12) size += 15;
    
    size += typeski
    document.sizeForm.ski.value = size;
  }
  else {
    alert("Please Fill in everything correctly")
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="sizeForm">
Age: <input type="text" name="age" size="10"><br />
Height: <input type="text" name="height" size="10"><br />
                 <select name="typeski" class="select" id="name" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type of ski" >
        <option value="0" disabled selected hidden>Please Select Type Of Skis. . . . . . .</option>
        <option value="10">Classic</option>
        <option value="20">Freestyle</option>
                </select>
<input type="button" value="Calculate Size" onClick="finalsize()"><br />
Your Ski Size: <input type="text" name="ski" size="10"><br />
<input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

Comment: thank you so much , that has helped a lot and ye was a big typo haha :) thanks again, i will try this now and then hopefully rebuild in vue xxx

Answer (score 0):

You should read which option is selected:

```
var sel = document.skiForm.typeski;
 var t= sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
```

And now you shoud compare the values and add extra cm:

```
if(skitype == "Classic") size += ....;
if(skitype == "Freestyle") size += ....;
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work because `skitype` will be `"0"` or `"1"` as those are the `value` attributes on the `<option>` elements used.

Comment: @Duncan Thacker You are right. I changed it to read text property.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the typeski variable and do an if else or a switch statement:

```
switch (typeski)
{
   case 0: //classic
      size += 10;
   break;
   case 1: //freestyle
       size += 10; //You said 10cm in your post. Change it if you need to.
   break;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vs2fu9qq/3/

Comment: This will work. I would usually recommend using a lookup object: `size += TYPE_SIZE_LOOKUP[ typeski ]` instead of `switch`.